# Automatically sync camera photos to folder when connected

Tags: windows-7, sync, iphone, automation, camera

I'd like to automatically sync the photos/movies on my iPhone to a folder on my Windows 7 PC each time the device is connected. I want this to happen without requiring any action, and ideally without launching any visible action or grabbing focus.

I've tried creating a scheduled task based on event log events (driver load) but then realised I couldn't get a path to the camera as Windows just shows it as below which isn't accessible from anywhere else.

```
Computer\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM
```

I see similar questions for USB storage devices, but not for cameras specifically which I can't create an autorun.inf on.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
KnownColor

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the app [Cloud Photos](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-photos/id507710836?mt=8) which syncs your images with Dropbox. You can get the Dropbox Win/Mac program and so your images will appear in C:/Users/USERNAME/Dropbox.